Does LangChain's AzureAISearchRetriever actually run a vector search?
When creating an instance of AzureAISearchRetriever I do not need to pass an embedding function and my OpenAI dashboard shows no activity when invoking the retriever.
However, the documentation suggests that a vector search is run:
https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/integrations/retrievers/azure_ai_search/
Am I missing something or does invoking the retriever just run a text search and no vector search?

I specified my service to my AzureSearch (vector database) for the retrieval and it just worked as expected.
retriever = AzureAISearchRetriever(
service_name= <service_name>,
api_key= <API Key>,
content_key="content", 
top_k=10, index_name=<indexname>)

